# How to create a user profile for; 'RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to create agents for my leads but I'm facing a challenge. When I execute my code it works, but when I want to create an agent this error pop's up. `leads.models.User.userprofile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile`

This is my `agents apps views.py`

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from leads.models import Agent
from .forms import AgentModelForm

class AgentListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "agents/agent_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Agent.objects.all()

class AgentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "agents/agent_create.html"
    form_class = AgentModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("agents:agent-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        agent = form.save(commit = False)
        agent.organisation = self.request.user.userprofile
        agent.save()
        return super(AgentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The 3rd line from the bottom is what I believe brings the error message. This is the full error message

```
Internal Server Error: /agents/create
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 143, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 182, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 151, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\djang0\agents\views.py", line 22, in form_valid
    agent.organisation = self.request.user.userprofile
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 253, in inner
    return func(_wrapped, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 524, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
leads.models.User.userprofile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile.
[22/Feb/2024 19:00:42] "POST /agents/create HTTP/1.1" 500 102374
```

Note: This is my first Django app and I'm still learning python. Any help will be highly apricated.

Comment: Share your models. The error means the user you are trying to access has no profile object. You can use django signals to automatically create profiles for users.

Comment: I have 3 apps. 1 is the website, 2 is the leads, 3 is the agents. So which models exactly? My agents models is practically empty. `from django.db import models` @NickLangat

Comment: do you have a model called profile? linked to a user model?